# Check createHandler() before closing form() vb.net

Tags: vb.net, forms, winforms

I'm currently running into a problem with a windows form application Closing.
I have multiple forms inside a main form. If I close the main form while one of the forms inside the main form is stil initializing the application crashes on Close() because createHandler() still running.

I already solved this inside one of the sub forms to add a boolean to Load() and check if the boolean is true. Example:

```
Private Sub frm_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
   ini = True
   // loading components etc.
   ini = False
End Sub

Private Sub frm_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles MyBase.KeyDown
If e.KeyData = Keys.Escape Then
      If (not ini)
          Close()
      End If
End If
```

Now I have simulair issue in the main form.

```
 Dim Childs = (From rec In Me.MdiChildren).ToList
 For Each Child In Childs
     Child.Close()
 Next
```

Is there anyway to verify if the childForm has been initialize before I close it?
something like: Child.IsInit()

Comment: Make the variable ini public, so that it can be accessed from main form. In your for loop (in main form) you can check if child's ini is true or false and act accordingly. Don't forget to check for Nothing to avoid any exception.

Comment: Any default ways to do this? It's over 100+ forms which I have to give a public bool just for solving this problem. A little cheat or hack is also fine to solve the problem. My only solution for now is try catch it so it won't close at all. But this will lead in a endless loop if any of those forms stuck in the Load(). So searching for a better solution to avoid future problems.

Comment: I can't think of any hack. If you go for try catch, then you can use counter to iterate forms in Childs. This will not cause infinite loop, but yes, few child forms will not be closed, then you can add a sleep or timer to try closing the left forms. Alternatively you can try a trick to declare public ini within 100 child forms. Replace "End Class" with "Public ini as Boolean newLineChar End Class" using some tools or writin your own code. Same trick you can use to update frm_Load with ini = False/ini=True.

Comment: Thanks, I'll stick to the try catch for now till I found another option.